# programmatically user confirm and news letter subscrip in magento(1.9.0.1)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, newsletter, user

case 1 : when i register via Facebook,i need to confirm the user and activate the newsletter subscription programmatically.

your support will help much more, thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily :

```
$customer=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
$customer->setConfirmation(true);
$customer->save();
```

for case of newsletter subscription try below:

```
$customer->setIsSubscribed(true);
    $customer->save();
```